# Constructor and different data types are confusing

Tags: java, string, types, constructor

I am passing a string through the constructor and assigning its value to a Grade type object class variable. I know it's very simple but I can't figure out to make this work. I cannot modify the variables or the constructor arguments, only implement the constructor.

I looked through the methods from string but couldn't figure out after an hour what to do. casting/converting/ idk

```
public class Course
{

private String courseNumber;
private int numberOfCredits;
private Grade gradeReceived;
private String termWhenTaken;

/**
 * The value for the courseNumber instance variable is converted to uppercase.
 * The numberOfCredits instance variable is set to the credits passed as a parameter if     it's 0 or more. 
 * Otherwise, it gets set to 0.
 */   
public Course(String course, int credits, String grade, String term) 
{    courseNumber = course.toUpperCase();
     numberOfCredits = credits; 
     termWhenTaken = term;
     gradeReceived = grade;   <-----problem here  mismatched data types obviously
}
```

Comment: It is hard to help without having a look at the Grade class since we don't know what it's constructor expects. The problem is that you are trying to assign a variable (gradeRecieved) to a value of a different type.

Comment: `gradeReceived = new Grade(grade);`

Comment: Oops , thank you -  here is the constructor "public Grade(String grade)"

Comment: Thank you @nachokk that fixed the problem.. can you explain how it works?

Comment: @XoronioX lookt at answer provided, says the same as me but with explanation bassicaly, java is strong type language, you can't assign a `String` to a `Grade` has nothing to do between, so you need a `Grade` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign an object of type A to a reference variable of type B (unless A is a subclass of B).  You can't assign a `String` to a `Grade`.

You will need to create a `Grade` using the `String`:

```
gradeReceived = new Grade(grade);
```

The `new` operator calls the constructor `public Grade(String grade)` and returns a new `Grade` object.

Comment: Thank you! problem solved. that is so incredibly simple lol. why do i not know that, my java teacher sucks?  =\

Comment: Done @nachokk do i need to close topics or just leave them answered?

Comment: @XoronioX leave them answered! people in the future with similar problems can view this question and solves their issue ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some sort of converter or mapping to convert a String value (say, "6th") to a Grade object.  Something like this could get you started:

```
public Course(String course, int credits, String grade, String term) {
    ...
    gradeReceived = convertGradeStringToGrade(grade);
    ...
}

private Grade convertGradeStringToGrade(String gradeStr) {
    if ("A".equals(gradeStr)) {
        return new Grade("A");
    } else if ("B".equals(gradeStr)) {
        return new Grade("B");
    } else if ... etc
    } else {
        // do something (throw an exception? return null?) if the string doesn't match a known grade
    }
}
```

Or you could just do something like

```
public Course(String course, int credits, String grade, String term) {
    ...
    gradeReceived = new Grade(grade);
    ...
}
```

if there isn't any conversion to be done.

You could also use an enum for your Grade object, but that might be beyond the scope of what you're trying to do currently.

Comment: Your method `convertStringToGrade` you should review.. -1

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes I did something very similar in the grade class. public Grade(String grade)
    {   
    if (grade.equals("a"))
    {letterGrade = grade.toUpperCase();
        numberValue = VALUE_OF_A;}  
    else if (grade.equals("A"))
    {letterGrade = grade.toUpperCase();
        numberValue = VALUE_OF_A;}   
    else if (grade.equals("b"))
    {letterGrade = grade.toUpperCase();
        numberValue = VALUE_OF_B;}